# Upgrade From PDF.js to PDF.js Express

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, pdf.js, struts-1

I'm working on a Java JSP Struts project which has previously implemented [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) for previewing documents. Because of the the PDF.js library didn't support watermarks option I decided to move to [PDF.js Express](https://pdfjs.express/).

The below code snippet is the previous implementation

**html body**

```
<iframe id="content" style='height: 600px; width: 98%; min-width: 900px;' scrolling="no" src=""></iframe>
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var base='web/viewer.html?file=';
        var subUrl=encodeURIComponent('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getImage.do?imageDocID='+document.getElementById('imageDocID').value);
        var url=base+subUrl+'#page=1';
        $('#content').attr('src',url);
    });
</script>
```

The `getImage.do` will go to the `GetImageAction.java` page and generate and get the PDF file,

**struts-config**

```
<action  
    path="/getImage"
    type="web.ead.webapp.ssd.common.action.GetImageAction"
    scope="request">
</action>
```

**GetImageAction.java**

```
public class GetImageAction extends GenericAction {
    
    static Object imageServerLock = new Object();
    
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException, Exception {

        UserProfile userProfile = (UserProfile) request.getSession().getAttribute("UserProfile");
        
        ActionForward actionForward = null;
        String imageDocID = request.getParameter("imageDocID");
        if (actionForward == null)
        {
            byte[] appletData = ImageManager.getMod2TifImage(imageDocID);
            ObjectOutputStream outputToApplet = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            outputToApplet.writeObject(appletData);
            outputToApplet.flush();
            outputToApplet.close();

            actionForward = null;
        }
        
        

        return actionForward;

        ActionForward actionForward = null;
        try{

            actionForward = super.execute(mapping, form, request, response);
            
            String imageDocID = request.getParameter("imageDocID");

            System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString() + "\trequest.getRemoteAddr() "
                    + request.getRemoteAddr() 
                    + " Utility.getClientIp(request) : "
                    + Utility.getClientIp(request) + " - " + imageDocID
                    + " UserProfileID: " + userProfile.getUserProfileID());
            byte[] image = null;
            synchronized (imageServerLock) {
                
                if(request.getSession().getAttribute("IMAGE-"+imageDocID) != null)
                    image = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("IMAGE-"+imageDocID);
                
                if (actionForward == null) {
                    byte[] dest = addWatemark(image);
                    
                    try{
                        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(dest);
                        int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        image = ImageManager.optimizePDF(image);
                        dest = addWatemark(image);
                    }
                    
                    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                    OutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
                    outs.write(dest);
                    outs.close();
                    actionForward = null;
                    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("IMAGE-"+imageDocID) != null)
                        request.getSession().removeAttribute("IMAGE-"+imageDocID);
                    
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        LoggerUtils.info(this.getClass().getName() + " - execute method --> Exit");
        return actionForward;
    }
```

When I added the new PDF.js Express it says to use the [this](https://pdfjs.express/documentation/get-started/manually) format.

Because I don't have a direct path of the generated pdf file I cannot use the `initialDoc` property.

Can you suggest me any solution to use PDF.js Express

Comment: It requires details, GetImageAction.java, struts-config.xml, etc.

Comment: @RomanC 
    
`<action  
  path="/getImage"
  type="web.ead.webapp.ssd.common.action.GetImageAction"
  scope="request">
 </action>`

this is the struts config file

Answer (score 0):

You can use a direct path to the image action.

```
initialDoc = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getImage.do?imageDocID='+document.getElementById('imageDocID').value;
```

Comment: I have tried that and this error shows in the PDF.js Express UI,

`File extension do%3fimagedocid%3dww222244 is not supported. Please see http://r.pdftron.com/fileformats for a full list of file formats supported by WebViewer.

If this file is actually valid then you can pass the 'extension' option with the intended file extension e.g. const doc = await Core.createDocument("http://domain/file11243. php", [extension: "pdf"})`

the initialDoc value is **%2FWEB_SSD%2FgetImage.do%3FimageDocID%3DWW222244** , So I think the string after **"."** is identified as the file extension.

Comment: Yes, it's a file extension. You need to add an extension option as said in the message.

Comment: **.do** isn't a file extension it's a routing technique to redirected to the specified Servlet in struts. But the **initialDoc**  requires a file path which has **.pdf**

So does anyone knows that, if I have the byte array of a pdf file, can I set it to this **initialDoc** or any other technique to use with the **WebViewer** in PDF.js Express?

Comment: I have seen in the documentation of WebViewer that it can use remote addresses to load a document and it doesn't matter what extention you use for the file.